# Why does shifting a numpy uint8 create negative values?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using python 2.7, numpy 1.6.1, 32-bit on windows.  I'm writing a function to pack some data into 32-bit integers and generating C source declarations from the constant values.  In doing so, I found some strange behavior in numpy's uint8 type.

No one is surprised, I'm sure, to see this:

```
>>> n = 0x94 << 24
>>> n
2483027968L
>>> hex(n)
'0x94000000L'
```

But do the same with a numpy uint8, and you get something that surprised me:

```
>>> n = np.uint8(0x94) << 24
>>> n
-1811939328
>>> hex(n)
'-0x6c000000'
```

One would think an explicitly unsigned type would be even less likely to return a negative value.

Note that values with the sign-bit clear work as expected:

```
>>> n = np.uint8(0x74) << 24
>>> n; hex(n)
1946157056
'0x74000000'
```

I happen to notice that numpy seems to be promoting unsigned types to signed types:

```
>>> n = np.uint8(0x74) << 24
>>> type(n)
<type 'numpy.int32'>
```

That seems a clear bug.  I can find no reference to such a known bug, but...is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`numpy` appears to treat the right-hand argument (`24`) as a signed integer of the native width (`int32` in your case, `int64` in mine).

It looks like the `uint8` gets promoted to the same type, and the result of the shift is also of the same type:

```
>>> np.uint8(0x94) << 56
-7782220156096217088
>>> type(np.uint8(0x94) << 56)
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

Making the right-hand argument into an unsigned `int` gives the result you expect:

```
>>> np.uint8(0x94) << np.uint(56)
10664523917613334528
>>> type(np.uint8(0x94) << np.uint(56))
<type 'numpy.uint64'>
>>> hex(np.uint8(0x94) << np.uint(56))
'0x9400000000000000L'
```